# QuarkusTest launches testcontainers though I didn't asked for it ; what's wrong?

Tags: java, unit-testing, rabbitmq, quarkus, smallrye-reactive-messaging

Very simple test case (no other code) :

```
@QuarkusTest
class EndpointTest {

    @Test
    void testPostMV() {
        fail("Not yet implemented"); // TODO
    }
}
```

POM.xml :

```
...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-rabbitmq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- TESTS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
...
```

When `mvn  -Dtest=org.avm.rest.EndpointTest test` I see in logs :

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running org.avm.rest.EndpointTest
2023-04-12 13:23:54,426 WARN  [io.qua.arc.dep.SplitPackageProcessor] (build-26) Detected a split package usage which is considered a bad practice and should be avoided. Following packages were detected in multiple archives: 
- "io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.connectors" found in [io.smallrye.reactive:smallrye-reactive-messaging-in-memory::jar, io.smallrye.reactive:smallrye-reactive-messaging-provider::jar]
2023-04-12 13:23:54,541 INFO  [org.tes.doc.DockerClientProviderStrategy] (build-26) Loaded org.testcontainers.dockerclient.UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy from ~/.testcontainers.properties, will try it first
2023-04-12 13:23:55,083 INFO  [org.tes.doc.DockerClientProviderStrategy] (build-26) Found Docker environment with local Unix socket (unix:///var/run/docker.sock)
2023-04-12 13:23:55,085 INFO  [org.tes.DockerClientFactory] (build-26) Docker host IP address is localhost
2023-04-12 13:23:55,102 INFO  [org.tes.DockerClientFactory] (build-26) Connected to docker: 
  Server Version: 23.0.3
  API Version: 1.42
  Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
  Total Memory: 31757 MB
2023-04-12 13:23:55,115 INFO  [org.tes.uti.ImageNameSubstitutor] (build-26) Image name substitution will be performed by: DefaultImageNameSubstitutor (composite of 'ConfigurationFileImageNameSubstitutor' and 'PrefixingImageNameSubstitutor')
2023-04-12 13:23:55,119 INFO  [org.tes.DockerClientFactory] (build-26) Checking the system...
2023-04-12 13:23:55,120 INFO  [org.tes.DockerClientFactory] (build-26) ✔︎ Docker server version should be at least 1.6.0
2023-04-12 13:23:55,188 INFO  [ .9-management]] (build-26) Creating container for image: rabbitmq:3.9-management
2023-04-12 13:23:55,211 INFO  [ .3.4]] (build-26) Creating container for image: testcontainers/ryuk:0.3.4
2023-04-12 13:23:55,346 INFO  [ .3.4]] (build-26) Container testcontainers/ryuk:0.3.4 is starting: ec8edc09f60e0179e1c6a9269e542a52f53de468fec15c1042ea7dde29aac2be
2023-04-12 13:23:55,859 INFO  [ .3.4]] (build-26) Container testcontainers/ryuk:0.3.4 started in PT0.648579S
2023-04-12 13:23:56,109 INFO  [ .9-management]] (build-26) Container rabbitmq:3.9-management is starting: a29cd698eed414e0ffa0ee2225d230504e6a332a022aec31f545104aa5f6ec85
2023-04-12 13:24:01,766 INFO  [ .9-management]] (build-26) Container rabbitmq:3.9-management started in PT6.63349S
```

If I suppress `quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-rabbitmq` from the POM file, then the simple test runs normally :

```
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running org.avm.rest.EndpointTest
2023-04-12 13:34:28,106 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) realtime_proxy_mt 2.16 on JVM (powered by Quarkus 2.16.1.Final) started in 1.880s. Listening on: http://localhost:8081
2023-04-12 13:34:28,111 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile test activated. 
2023-04-12 13:34:28,111 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [cdi, rabbitmq-extension, resteasy-reactive, smallrye-context-propagation, smallrye-openapi, swagger-ui, vertx]
[ERROR] Tests run: 3, Failures: 3, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.319 s <<< FAILURE! - in org.avm.rest.EndpointTest
```

Nowhere I set testContainer ; I don'tunderstand Why it is launched...
I have another project with the same dependencies which doesn't launch testcontainers for tests ; I don't see any difference ...
I am stuck.
Is there someone else in the same situation ?
Some hints, maybe ?

Comment: if not explicitly disabled for test profile, devservices are started in both dev and test.

Answer (score 1):

For those who don't see little lines (like me) : `Dev Services for RabbitMQ automatically starts a RabbitMQ broker in dev mode and when running tests. So, you don’t have to start a broker manually.`, the answer is here : https://quarkus.io/guides/rabbitmq-dev-services...