# Quarkus always starts Testcontainers when running tests with @QuarkusTest, even if the test doesn't use Testcontainers

Tags: java, containers, quarkus, testcontainers, quarkus-testing

After configuring Testcontainers in my project, Quarkus keeps starting a container every time I run a test with @QuarkusTest, even if the test doesn't use Testcontainers.

My Testcontainers configuration:

```
@Testcontainers
public class MongoIntegrationTest {

  @Container
  public static final MongoDBContainer mongoDBContainer = new MongoDBContainer(
      DockerImageName.parse("mongo:4.2.3"))
      .withExposedPorts(27017);

  public static class Initializer implements QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager {

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> start() {
      MongoIntegrationTest.mongoDBContainer.start();
      // the way to dynamically expose allocated port
      return Maps.of("quarkus.mongodb.connection-string",
          "mongodb://" + mongoDBContainer.getHost() + ":"
              + mongoDBContainer.getMappedPort(27017));
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
      MongoIntegrationTest.mongoDBContainer.stop();
    }
  }

}
```

My test that requires Testcontainers, as it uses MongoDB:

```
@QuarkusTest
@QuarkusTestResource(MongoIntegrationTest.Initializer.class)
public class ClassMongoTest {

  @Test
  void test(){
    Assertions.assertTrue(true);
  }

}
```

But now, any class configured with @QuarkusTest is starting the MongoDB container...

```
@QuarkusTest
class ClassNormalTest {

  @Test
  void test(){
    Assertions.assertTrue(true);
  }

}
```

So, when I run my ClassNormalTest, Quarkus starts the containers...

[Printscreen showing the Testcontainers containers:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fiml.png)

Why? What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: This works as described in https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#quarkus-test-resource -- which also describes a workaround you can use: `@QuarkusTestResource(restrictToAnnotatedClass = true)`.

Comment: What's the reason you're explicitly managing the MongoDB container with testcontainers instead of just using [dev services](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-dev-services)? It's possible that if you just remove `MongoIntegrationTest` from your codebase, as long as you have the Quarkus MongoDB extension in your pom, other tests that use Mongo will continue passing. This doesn't really address your question, but it would save you some code.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75995057/quarkustest-launches-testcontainers-though-i-didnt-asked-for-it-whats-wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this on your test class:

```java
@QuarkusTestResource(value = MongoIntegrationTest.Initializer.class, restrictToAnnotatedClass = true)
```

This will only startup Mongo on this test class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Quarkus does currently always start Testcontainers when running tests with `@QuarkusTest`, even if the test doesn't use Testcontainers. This is because Quarkus uses Testcontainers to provide Dev Services, which are automatically provisioned services that can be used in development and test mode.

Here are a few ways to prevent Quarkus from starting Testcontainers when running tests:

- Use the `quarkus.datasource.start-container` property. Set this
  property to `false` to disable the automatic starting of Testcontainers
  containers for databases.
- Use a custom `QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager` implementation. This allows you to have complete control over which Testcontainers containers are
  started and stopped before and after your tests run.
- Exclude the `quarkus-testcontainers` extension from your application. This will prevent Quarkus from loading the Testcontainers extension, and
  therefore prevent it from starting Testcontainers containers.

Comment: These are settings to completely disable off devservices. The OP wants to disable devservices only on other tests which don't have any MongoDB requirement.